# Expectation throwing balls into boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation

I was thinking about this situation:

Suppose there are $n$ boxes. In each box we randomly throw one of the  balls numbered $1,2,\ldots,k$, independently of other boxes. Let $X$ be the number of boxes with ball number $1$. What is $E[X]$, and what is $E[\dfrac{1}{X}\mid X>0]$?

It seems that there should be "roughly" $n/k$ boxes with ball number $1$, so $E[X]=n/k$, and $E[\dfrac{1}{X}\mid X>0]=k/n$. But is it right?

**Edit**: I've asked a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556083/computing-e1-x-for-binomial-x) to make it direct to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about $E[X]$ but wrong about $E[1/X]$.  Since $X$ can take the value $0$ with nonzero probability, $E[1/X]$ is undefined.

**Added after OP's edit**:  Even if you condition on $X$ being positive, $k/n$ can't be the right answer in general.  Since $X$ is the number of boxes with ball number 1, it's a whole number and consequently $1/X\le1$ if $X\gt0$, which means the expected value can't exceed $1$.  But $k/n\gt1$ if $k\gt n$.

Comment: That's a good point, Barry. I want to condition it on $X>0$. Please see my edit.

Comment: (Responding to your edit) You're right. I've asked a new question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556083/computing-e1-x-for-binomial-x) instead.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p=1/k$. A succes if ball number $1$ is thrown, a failure otherwise.